# How to fix "'bool' object is not iterable" error when running a UNIX command on a directory of files in python

Tags: python, unix

I am trying to run a list of files in a directory through a UNIX executable using a python. I would the output of the executable for each file written to a different directory but retaining the original filename.

I am using python 2.7 so using the subprocess.call method. I am getting an error that says "'bool' object is not iterable" which I am guessing is due to the part where I am trying to write the output files as when I run the following script through the console I get an expected output specific to the executable within the console window:

```
import subprocess
import os

for inp in os.listdir('/path/to/input/directory/'):
    subprocess.call(['/path/to/UNIX/executable', inp])
```

My code is currently this:

```
import subprocess
import os

for inp in os.listdir('/path/to/input/directory/'):
    out = ['/path/to/output/directory/%s' % inp]
    subprocess.call(['/path/to/UNIX/executable', inp] > out)
```

However, this second lot of code returns the "'bool' is not iterable" error.

I'm guessing the solution is pretty trivial as it is not a complicated task however, as a beginner, I do not know where to start!

SOLVED: following @barak-itkin's answer, for those who may stumble across this issue in the future, the code ran successfully using the following:

```
import subprocess
import os

for inp in os.listdir('/path/to/input/directory/'):
    with open('/path/to/output/directory/%s' % inp, 'w') as out_file:
        subprocess.call(['/path/to/UNIX/executable', inp], stdout=out_file)
```

Comment: @roganjosh no, the first snippet runs fine the second snippet returns the error, I shall update to be more clear.

Comment: `>` is a greater-than comparison. It returns a boolean value. `subprocess.call(True)` makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write the output of a subprocess.call to a file, you would need to either use the `> path/to/out` as part of the command itself, or to do it "properly" by specifying the file to which the output should go:

```
# Option 1:
# Specify that the command is using a "shell" syntax, meaning that
# things like output redirection (such as with ">") should be handled
# by the shell that will evaluate the command
subprocess.call('my_command arg1 arg2 > /path/to/out', shell=True)

# Option 2:
# Open the file to which you want to write the output, and then specify
# the `stdout` parameter to be that file
with open('/path/to/out', 'w') as out_file:
    subprocess.call(['my_command', 'arg1', 'arg2'], stdout=out_file)
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Perfect, the second option worked flawlessly. Thanks! :D